# What is the difference between a service and a library?

Tags: service, libraries

That is, in the general programming sense of the words.

From my understanding, both appear to be an outside collection of code imported to use in projects to abstract programming and make it easier. Can you not call methods in services like you can in libraries? I also saw some stuff on service-orientated programming that confused me a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A service** is typically running on a separate server and you use a service's functionality by communicating with it with a protocol, e.g. a HTTP request for a webservice.

**A library** on the other hand is code that is directly integrated into your own code.

However, both a library and a service should provide you a stable, well-documented interface and they are similar in that sense.

Comment: I think this answer is a little incomplete. I came to this question to learn about the difference between a library and a service (as in DDD). Since both (seem to) act as collections of methods, the confusion is inevitable.